# Is there a way to tell a View in ASP.NET where to look for a Web.Config?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've recently began a new project and I've decided to try to arrange the folders in a basic ASP.NET MVC project by feature (i.e. one folder would contain all Account files Models, View and Controller and another folder would contain Home Model, View and Controller etc...) instead of the default ASP.NET template. With this being said I quickly realized when I moved my views my controller was looking under the views folder. I fixed that but then my views were looking for the Web.Config and I fixed that by copying the views folder Web.Config into that folder. This is a solution but I want to know if I can point all my views to one Web.Config without having to have them all in the same folder.

Comment: MVC follows a Convention Over Configuration paradigm so you're fighting the framework when you move stuff around like that. There are also [Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas) which gives you another level of organization.

Comment: @Jasen Ok, that actually makes a lot of sense. I don't need to do it this way. I just wanted to but I think I'll just stick with the template the framework provides.

Answer (score 0):

Every folder in ASP.NET web application / website can have its own web.config file. Having said that, it is also necessary that the root folder of your application must have a web.config file based on which the application / website will be configured in the hosting environment.

Therefore, if you want to use different settings for different folders, you can place a separate web.config file with settings specific to folder in the any of the application folder.